# how to uninstall a binary from GAC in windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, gac

i need to delete a binary from GAC in win 7..I know how it works for win xp but i cannot go through the same procedure in win 7

Comment: Why can't you go through the same procedure? By the way could you provide a little more details about this famous procedure that you are using and explain how it doesn't work in Win7? Also I hope you are aware that the location of the GAC has changed in .NET 4.0 and is no longer `C:\Windows\assembly`.

Comment: gacutil /u <assembly name> from a command prompt started in Admin mode.

Comment: in xp we just goto->assembly->Right click uninstall... we cannot follow this procedure in win 7...But the second one u mentioned is the right way..Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this on a command prompt:

```
gacutil /u <assembly name>
```

The keyword above is `<assembly name>`. Perhaps you are using `<DLL filename>` which is a common mistake. It doesn't work that way!

If you don't know the assembly name, try this second command...

```
gacutil /l > C:\GAC_Assemblies.txt
```

...and then search for your DLL filename inside the contents of the resulting C:\GAC_Assemblies.txt file. Note the corresponding assembly name and use that when you retry the first command!